# dd command writing to /dev/sdc changed size of disk

Tags: dd, external-hdd

I used a dd command to write directly to /dev/sdc (an externally mounted hdd 1TB size) to test various writing speeds in a raw mode.  (I don't care about any data on the disk).  Now the size of the disk as reported by fdisk or gparted is the size of the data I wrote, and I cannot figure out how to get the full disk size back.

The command I used was:

dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdc bs=4096 count=[big number]

As shown below, if I write 128KB of data using this command, then fdisk reports the drive as only 128KB in size.  When I try to write up to 1TB
of data, it stops at 30GB with device full error.

I have tried deleting and recreating partition tables, but since the software only recognizes the smaller drive size, that doesn't help.

How do I get the full drive size back?

P.S. I also tried writing from if=/dev/zero instead.  That goes at 5GB/s and stops at the same 32GB spot.

P.P.S. I also tried removing power from the drive and restarting it, thinking there was something in memory causing the problem.  Same issue.

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 29.5 GiB, 31633203200 bytes, 61783600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

#try to write to entire drive:
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=65536 count=15258788 status=progress

26753171456 bytes (27 GB, 25 GiB) copied, 5.00001 s, 5.4 GB/s
dd: error writing '/dev/sdc': No space left on device
482685+0 records in
482684+0 records out
31633203200 bytes (32 GB, 29 GiB) copied, 5.89003 s, 5.4 GB/s

# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdc bs=65536 count=2 status=progress
2+0 records in
2+0 records out
131072 bytes (131 kB, 128 KiB) copied, 0.000660426 s, 198 MB/s

# fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 128 KiB, 131072 bytes, 256 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdc bs=65536 count=15258788 status=progress
31624462336 bytes (32 GB, 29 GiB) copied, 136 s, 233 MB/s     
dd: error writing '/dev/sdc': No space left on device
482685+0 records in
482684+0 records out
31633203200 bytes (32 GB, 29 GiB) copied, 136.038 s, 233 MB/s
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a file on your root device rather than a device at /dev/sdc. What does `ls -l /dev/sdc` say?

Comment: #ls -l /dev/sdc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 31633203200 Jan 11 13:09 /dev/sdc

wow!  How do I fix that?

Comment: I deleted the /dev/sdc and /dev/sdc1 files (they were not block devices but just files), and re-plugged the drive.  /dev/sdc appeared and `fdisk -l /dev/sdc`  reports the correct size.  I think all is well.  Somehow, I must have done the dd command when the drive was not plugged in and it created the files in /dev instead.  After that, things went downhill quickly.  @icarus if you write up your comment as an answer, I will accept it.  Thank you.

Comment: @icarus You should make that an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some reason the block special device file /dev/sdc didn't exist, perhaps because the drive wasn't connected at the time. The `dd` command then created the file as a normal file, probably on the root filesystem, which gives the observed results.

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer fits the facts and is accepted.